# issue with np.where() for creating new column in Pandas (possibly NaN issue?)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, and I want to create a 3rd column based on a comparison between the 2 columns.

So the logic is:
column 1 val = 3, column 2 val = 4, so the new column value is nothing

column 1 val = 3, column 2 val = 2, so the new column is 3

It's a very similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680666/creating-a-new-column-in-panda-by-using-lambda-function-on-two-existing-columns) to one previously asked but the answer there isn't working for me, using np.where()

Here's what I tried:

```
FinalDF['c'] = np.where(FinalDF['a']>FinalDF['b'],[FinalDF['a'],""])
```

and after that failed I tried to see if maybe it doesn't like the [x,y] I gave it, so I tried:

```
FinalDF['c'] = np.where(FinalDF['a']>FinalDF['b'],[1,0])
```

the result is always:

```
ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

Edit: I also removed the [x,y], to see what happens, since the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) says it is optional.  But I still get an error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Which is odd because they are sitting in the same dataframe, *although one column does have some Nan values.*

I don't think I can [use np.select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45609903/np-where-on-multiple-variables) because I have a condition here.  I've linked to the previous questions so readers can reference them in future questions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your condition describes different logic compared to code? It should be like this `np.where(FinalDF['a']>FinalDF['b'],"",[FinalDF['b']])`.

Answer (score 3):

I think that this should work:

```
FinalDF['c'] = np.where(FinalDF['a']>FinalDF['b'], FinalDF['a'],"")
```

Example:

```
FinalDF = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,2,4,5,5,4],
               'b':[4,3,2,2,2,4],
               })
print FinalDF
   a  b
0  4  4
1  2  3
2  4  2
3  5  2
4  5  2
5  4  4
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  4  4   
1  2  3   
2  4  2  4
3  5  2  5
4  5  2  5
5  4  4
```

or if the column `b` has to have a greater value of column `a`, use this:

```
FinalDF['c'] = np.where(FinalDF['a']<FinalDF['b'], FinalDF['b'],"")
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  4  4   
1  2  3  3
2  4  2   
3  5  2   
4  5  2   
5  4  4
```

Comment: the logic doesn't match the `np.where` condition.

Comment: @shivsn example in the documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html : `np.where(x < 5, x, -1)`